# Javascript: length doesn't work on arrays that are inside an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to create an object such that `object.a` is an array while `object.b` is the length of it and this is what I have:

```
var object = {
   a:[1,2,3,2],
   b: this.a.length
}
alert(b);
```

But this won't alert 4. There is something wrong with `b: this.a.length`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

---

I'd be glad if someone can explain to me why this is happening.

It would actaully alert 4 if I write it this way:

```
 var object = {
       a:[1,2,3,2]
 }
    alert(object.a.length);
```

---

[update] even create the object this way, it doesn't work:

```
var object = {
   a:[1,2,3,2],
   b：object.a.length
}
```

Comment: your update does not work because you're trying to refer to a variable before it's been declared (think about R to L evaluation javascript uses)

Comment: @jbabey yeah I get it now. Thank you guys so much for answering the question! Those are all great answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that in javascript data declaration like your first example, the value of `this` is not set to the object being defined.  So since `this` is not your object, `this.a` inside the object declaration does not refer to the `a` property of your object.

It is whatever it was in the context right before your data declaration.  If that was the global context, then `this` would be the `window` object and `this.a` probably doesn't exist.  If it doesn't exist (e.g. it's `undefined`), then when you try to reference `this.a.length`, you are trying to read the property `.length` off something isn't an object and that is a javscript error.

---

As for solving this problem it is generally a bad idea to copy the length of an array to another property.  That just gives you a chance for it to be wrong and out-of-sync with the actual length of the array.  If you want the length of the array, you should just retrieve it upon demand with:

```
object.a.length
```

If you really want it to be a property (that has a fixed value and doesn't change when `a` changes), you can set it after you create the object:

```
var object = {
   a:[1,2,3,2],
};
object.b = object.a.length;
alert(object.b);
```

Comment: I'm not sure the word "static" is appropriate here. Is it?

Answer (score 1):

all properties of an object are instantiated at once, so `this` refers to the window object when creating the property `b`. You'd need to defer the interpretation of `b`'s value, one way is to use a function instead:

```
var object = {
    a:[1,2,3,2],
    b: function () {
        return this.a.length;
    }
}
```

Another way is to add the property `b` after the object literal has been declared:

```
var object = {
    a:[1,2,3,2]
}
object.b = object.a.length;
```

Finally, on newer browsers you can take advantage of a getter:

```
var object = {
    a:[1,2,3,2],
    get b() {
        return this.a.length;            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example 'b' is undefined, because it is looking for a variable named 'b' not the property 'b' inside of the object 'object'.  You should use object.b instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add `b` to the object after creating it:

```
var object = {
    a:[1,2,3,2]
}

object.b = object.a.length
```